# svn branch has directories committed that are unversioned and should stay that way (not have been committed), how do I remove them from banch?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

A developer committed changes to a branch.  The changes also added several directories that should stay unversioned.  I noticed this when I did switch on the test server to the branch this individual was working with:

```
svn: Failed to add directory 'media/css': an unversioned directory of the same name already exists
```

Due to this issue, the full branch was not checked out on the test server.  How may I "fix" the branch such that the unversioned directories would be removed from the commit?  NOTE: I must reserve the content in the unversioned directories prior to the branch switch (I do not want them in svn).

Thank you for your time and assistance.

Comment: Do you want to exclude `/media/css` that's versioned in the repository? Why don't you checkout a clean working copy?